# Python Process only spawning one process in loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, parallel-processing, subprocess, python-multithreading

I have a Python 3.7 program I'm writing that has a main script `a.py` that creates an instance of a class in another script `b.py`. I want `a.py` to be able to create multiple simultaneous instances of my class in `b.py`, but the code I'm using to call `b.py` seems to only spawn one instance at a time.

The code I have looks like this:

```
import b
from multithreading import Process

processes = []
while (True):
    dataFiles = getFilesFromDatabase()
    if len(dataFiles) > 0:
        for file in dataFiles:
            p = Process(target=b.class, args=(file,), name=file['name'])
            p.start()
            processes.append(p)

    sleep(60)
```

When `dataFiles` (a list of dictionaries) has multiple dictionaries, a `Process` is spawned for `dataFiles[0]`, but `dataFiles[1]` is not started until after `dataFiles[0]` finishes. I'm not calling `Process.join()` anywhere so I'm not sure what could be wrong. Do I need to use a `Pool` for this? Is there anything else I'm missing?

Any help appreciated!

Comment: I'm no multithreading expert, but sounds like `p` is just being overwritten. You could store them in a dict where the keys are the file names or something

Comment: it's not the issue. p is stored in the list, so garbage collection couldn't even take place

Comment: creating a process takes some time. How much tme does your processing take? if it's a few seconds, that could be perfectly normal.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre it takes about 5 minutes normally for each process to run, since they're such lengthy processes I was wondering if that could be part of the problem. Should I not be storing p anywhere and just letting it terminate on its own?

Comment: have you tried reducing your code to a [mcve] ? in this process you could understand why it behaves like that (I/O bound, something else...)